# Type hints for pytests fixtures that return methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pytest

Some of my pytest fixtures return a method. I would like to use type hints for all my methods. To say that a method return a method I can use `Callable` here. The problem here: I'm loosing the autocompletion feature for the arguments in my IDE PyCharm.

Without giving a type hint for the return value of the fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def create_project():
    def create(location: Path, force: bool = True) -> bool:
        # ...

    return create


def test_project(create_project):
    project_created = create_project()
```

[image]

With a given type hint:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def create_project() -> Callable[[Path, bool], bool]:
    def create(location: Path, force: bool = True) -> bool:
        # ...

    return create


def test_project(create_project):
    project_created = create_project()
```

[image]

Another problem with `Callable` is, that I have to describe the arguments and return type once in the fixture and in every test where I use this fixture.

So is there any more efficient way to do it?

Comment: N.B. Functions that return functions are often called "factory functions"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The intended way seems to be using [Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol):

```py
from typing import Protocol


class ProjectMaker(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, location: Path, force: bool = True) -> bool: ...


@pytest.fixture
def create_project() -> ProjectMaker:
    def create(location: Path, force: bool = True) -> bool:
        ...

    return create


def test_project(create_project: ProjectMaker):
    project_created = create_project()
```

<strike>Unfortunately this is currently not supported in PyCharm ([#PY-45438](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-45438))</strike>

Comment: `def test_project(create_project: ProjectMaker) -> None: ...`

Comment: "The intended way seems to be": seems according to who? It would be nice if there was a link to some documentation here.

Comment: Agreed. Protocol is not intended for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

[Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol)s are, more specifically, intended for implementing duck-typing (think the "Iterable protocol", for example). The problem with the above usage is that *any* object that implements `__call__` with the signature shown will be considered a `ProjectMaker`. (see [Carl Meyer's PyCon 2018 presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMgmKJyWKn8) for an example).

I believe an acceptable alternative is to use a `TypeAlias` to make your type hinting easier:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import TypeAlias

ProjectMaker: TypeAlias = Callable[[Path, bool], bool]

# Now use `ProjectMaker` throughout as before...
```

It's also shorter. Note that you don't have to use `TypeAlias`. It is there purely to make it explicit that the statement is a type alias and not a normal variable declaration. (see [Type aliases](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases) from the docs)

***ASIDE:*** A short rule of thumb I use to determine whether to use `Protocol` is if what I'm talking about is "-able" (Iterable, Callable, Reversible, Mutable, Mappable, etc.). If so, I'm describing a behavior, and `Protocol` is a good bet.

Comment: Using a type alias solves the problem of repeating myself. But it doesn't solve the problem, that the IDE doesn't tell me how the parameters are called.

Comment: I would recommend adding a docstring, which may help with the Intellisense.